# Extra columns appearing while running loop in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as following:

```
     word count    word  tf score word probability log values TFxIDF score
1   yemen   380   yemen 1.0000000       0.05393896   2.919902     2.919902
2 strikes   116 strikes 0.3052632       0.01646558   4.106483     1.253558
```

But when I run the following code:

```
p1 <- read.csv("F:/M.Tech/Semester4/Thesis/Code/a1.csv")
x <- nrow(p1)
q <- p1[1,2]

for(i in 1:x) {
  p1[i,4]=p1[i,2]/q
}

for(i in 1:x) {
  p1[i,5]=p1[i,2]/p
}

for(i in 1:x) {
  p1[i,6]= -log(p1[i,5])
}

for(i in 1:x) {
  p1[i,7]= p1[i,4]*p1[i,6]
}
```

I get the other data frame with extra columns as:

```
   NA    word count    word  tf score word probability log values TFxIDF score Keyword Probability
1   1   yemen   380   yemen 1.0000000       0.05393896   2.919902     2.919902                  NA
2   2 strikes   116 strikes 0.3052632       0.01646558   4.106483     1.253558                 0.5
```

How can I remove these extra columns from coming?

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability. Please check to make sure it reflects your data accurately.

Comment: Hey. Thanks jbaums, yes it reflects my code and problem perfectly.. thanks for your help

Comment: You don't need loops to do all the work. `p1$tf <- p1$count/q` will also work (in place of the first loop).

Comment: The code works just fine for me. I'm guessing that that csv file you read it has row numbers in the data. At any rate, have you tried `p1$NA <- NULL`?

Comment: hi goodtimeslim, thanks for your help. I am able to delete the new column like this, But while naming the new column i am not able to name it as:

Comment: colnames(s1) <- c("word", "count","word","tf score","word robability","log values","TFxIDF score","Keyword Probability","Keyword Score")

Comment: but in return it returns the column name as V9:  word count word.1 tf score word robability log values TFxIDF score Keyword Probability V9
1 yemen 380 yemen 1 0.053938964 2.919902172 2.919902172 NA NA
2 strikes 116 strikes 0.305263158 0.016465578 4.106483233 1.25355804 0.5 0.62677902